# Postgres query to return JSON object keys as array

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, array, json

Is it possible to return a JSON object keys as an array of values in PostgreSQL?

In JavaScript, this would simply be `Object.keys(obj)`, which returns an array of strings.

For example, if I have a table like this:

```
tbl_items
---------
id bigserial NOT NULL
obj json NOT NULL
```

And if there's a row like this:

```
id      obj
-----   -------------------------
123     '{"foo":1,"bar":2}'
```

How can I have a query to return:

```
id      keys
-----   ------------------
123     '{"foo","bar"}'
```

Comment: Here's an additional postgresql JSON question you might find interesting: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/281480/45101

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Sure, with [`json_object_keys()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE). This returns a *set* - unlike the JavaScript function `Object.keys(obj)` you are referring to, which returns an *array*. Feed the set to an [`ARRAY` constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) to transform it:

```
SELECT id, ARRAY(SELECT json_object_keys(obj)) AS keys
FROM   tbl_items;
```

Or use [`jsonb_object_keys()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) for `jsonb`.

This returns an array of keys *per row* (not for the whole table).

A more verbose form would be to spell out a `LATERAL` join instead of the correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t.id, k.keys
FROM   tbl_items t
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (SELECT ARRAY(SELECT * FROM json_object_keys(t.obj)) AS keys) k ON true;
```