# Unpacking JSON into 14 columns without crosstab() and tablefunc?

Tags: postgresql, json, postgresql-12

In a Postgres 12 database, I have a simple schema containing a JSON column.  The JSON will always contain an object, and inside the object there are always 14 keys like so:

```
CREATE TABLE json_unpacking (foo text, bar json);
INSERT INTO json_unpacking VALUES
(
'ziggy',
'{"Baz (1998-03-12)":1.4285714286,"Baz (1998-03-13)":7.1428571429,"Baz (1998-03-14)":10.8571428571,"Baz (1998-03-15)":11.2857142857,"Baz (1998-03-16)":12.0,"Baz (1998-03-17)":18.1428571429,"Baz (1998-03-18)":2.0,"Baz (1998-03-19)":2.5714285714,"Baz (1998-03-20)":12.2857142857,"Baz (1998-03-21)":3.2857142857,"Baz (1998-03-22)":5.5734285714,"Baz (1998-03-23)":4.1428571429,"Baz (1998-03-24)":11.2857142857,"Baz (1998-03-25)":6.0}'
),
(
'zoggy',
'{"Baz (1998-04-12)":1.7285714286,"Baz (1998-04-13)":6.8578886549,"Baz (1998-04-14)":6.8574428571,"Baz (1998-04-15)":21.2857142857,"Baz (1998-04-16)":7.0,"Baz (1998-04-17)":3.1128571429,"Baz (1998-04-18)":5.0,"Baz (1998-04-19)":7.2214285714,"Baz (1998-04-20)":42.6857142857,"Baz (1998-04-21)":2.9857142857,"Baz (1998-04-22)":5.5734285714,"Baz (1998-04-23)":4.1428571429,"Baz (1998-03-24)":6.7537146517,"Baz (1998-04-25)":47.0}'
)
;
```

I'm able to query this table just fine, for instance:

```
SELECT *
FROM json_unpacking
```

Produces the output that you'd expect:

| foo | bar |
| --- | --- |
| ziggy | {"Baz (1998-03-12)":1.4285714286,"Baz (1998-03-13)":7.1428571429,"Baz (1998-03-14)":10.8571428571,"Baz (1998-03-15)":11.2857142857,"Baz (1998-03-16)":12.0,"Baz (1998-03-17)":18.1428571429,"Baz (1998-03-18)":2.0,"Baz (1998-03-19)":2.5714285714,"Baz (1998-03-20)":12.2857142857,"Baz (1998-03-21)":3.2857142857,"Baz (1998-03-22)":5.5734285714,"Baz (1998-03-23)":4.1428571429,"Baz (1998-03-24)":11.2857142857,"Baz (1998-03-25)":6.0} |
| zoggy | {"Baz (1998-04-12)":1.7285714286,"Baz (1998-04-13)":6.8578886549,"Baz (1998-04-14)":6.8574428571,"Baz (1998-04-15)":21.2857142857,"Baz (1998-04-16)":7.0,"Baz (1998-04-17)":3.1128571429,"Baz (1998-04-18)":5.0,"Baz (1998-04-19)":7.2214285714,"Baz (1998-04-20)":42.6857142857,"Baz (1998-04-21)":2.9857142857,"Baz (1998-04-22)":5.5734285714,"Baz (1998-04-23)":4.1428571429,"Baz (1998-03-24)":6.7537146517,"Baz (1998-04-25)":47.0} |

Now, I'd like to query this table and produce a structure with 15 total columns: `"foo"` plus 14 like `"bar 1", "bar 2", ... "bar 14"`.

The JSON structure will always include a string pattern (which includes the date), and a numeric value.  I do not want the key value, but I need the number values transposed into columns.

In other words, the output structure that I want is like so:

| foo | bar 1 | bar 2 | bar 3 | bar 4 | bar 5 | bar 6 | bar 7 | bar 8 | bar 9 | bar 10 | bar 11 | bar 12 | bar 13 | bar 14 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ziggy | 1.428571429 | 7.142857143 | 10.85714286 | 11.28571429 | 12 | 18.14285714 | 2 | 2.571428571 | 12.28571429 | 3.285714286 | 5.573428571 | 4.142857143 | 11.28571429 | 6 |
| zoggy | 1.728571429 | 6.857888655 | 6.857442857 | 21.28571429 | 7 | 3.112857143 | 5 | 7.221428571 | 42.68571429 | 2.985714286 | 5.573428571 | 4.142857143 | 6.753714652 | 47 |

I suppose I have two questions:

1. Is this possible?
2. Can it be done without any extension?

A colleague has suggested that the [`crosstab()` function from the tablefunc extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/tablefunc.html) might be required.  I've tried various Postgres JSON functions, but have only succeeded in getting either the keys (e.g. using `json_object_keys()`) or null values (using `json_to_record()`).

Here's a DBfiddle of the problem: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=22e9c99a954eafdadcde657b38f41b3a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a JSON path query:

```
select foo, 
       items ->> 0 as bar_1, 
       items ->> 1 as bar_2, 
       items ->> 1 as bar_3, 
       .....
from ( 
  select foo, jsonb_path_query_array(bar::jsonb, '$.*') as items
  from json_unpacking
) as t
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=59118e00c038b6372b79188d8e70beb9)

---

Note that it's recommended to use `jsonb` over `json` (and in this case it would avoid the cast)

Comment: Thank you so much, this was very helpful!  I'll add that this style also allows use of multiple JSON columns, e.g. `... 
jsonb_path_query_array(bar::jsonb, '$.*') as bar,
jsonb_path_query_array("bar baz"::jsonb, '$.*') as bar_baz,
...
`

Comment: Is there a option for versions <12 ?

Answer (score 2):

Unpack your JSON to separate rows using

```
SELECT json_unpacking.foo, 
       values.value, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY foo) value_number
FROM json_unpacking
CROSS JOIN json_each(json_unpacking.bar) values
```

Then combine it back into needed row structure using grouping and conditional aggregation.

Comment: Thank you so much @Akina .  Ultimately, I used the other solution, but the answer you provided is very interesting and I'm sure it will help many others.